# How do I run my first ruby app on my server now that its done?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger, rack, resque

So I've successfully finished my first ruby app :)

When i programmed it locally, i have to use all the following commands below separately in terminal to get it up and running. The problem is when I close terminal they all stop, so I don't know how to keep them open even when i log out of ssh on my server.

First I get the app running via rack (sinatra framework) on port 9292, then start redis, and then create a single worker for 2 Resque job queues

```
rackup config.ru
redis-server
rake workers:start
```

I haven't been using "production/development" structures simply because I haven't really learned about that yet. I'm just trying to get it set up simply, then I can go back and learn how all that works. So i understand this isnt the best method for a professional app, but right now I'm looking for the easiest (but still without taking shortcuts).

I also believe I'm going to be using passenger to get it officially running. I'm not sure what the next steps are to get it up and running so i can log out and it just stays active and working. I also dont know if i have to run the commands separately or if I can put them all in one file somewhere so i just run `passenger start` and thats the end of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use Passenger to host your application then you won't be running *commands* to start the server; instead, the application will simply run as part of [`nginx`](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app) or [`httpd`](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application_including_rails_gt_3), which will be started via the system's `init(8)` tool.

How `init(8)` is configured varies considerably from system to system, but [SysV-style `init`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style) will typically have scripts in `/etc/rc*.d/*` directories to control startup, [Upstart-based systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) will have config files in `/etc/init/`, and so on. At that point, you're not looking for ways to run `passenger` applications so much as a way to start Apache `httpd` or `nginx`, and that's an already well-solved problem.

Comment: I'm using apache and liquidweb. Your answer helps but I'm still not sure exactly what the next step is (or even what to google)

Comment: Do you have passenger configured on your Apache yet? If not, start with the `httpd` link from above, it's got installation guidelines for Apache.